# XML typeof return nothing (PHP + RSS)

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have a pretty annoying issue. I'm getting a RSS flow.

I need to get the image that is inside my  tag. But as you see, the RSS flow is not optimised.

See this example of item :

```
<item>
    <title>Element !</title>
    <link>
    link</link>
    <description>&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-hidden&quot;&gt;&lt;div
        class=&quot;field-items&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-item even&quot; rel=&quot;og:image rdfs:seeAlso&quot;
        resource=&quot;http://www.test.com/sites/default/files/field/image/image.jpg&quot;&gt;&lt;img typeof=&quot;foaf:Image&quot;
        src=&quot;http://www.test.com/sites/default/files/field/image/image.jpg&quot; width=&quot;800&quot; height=&quot;571&quot;
        alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-body
        field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-items&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-item
        even&quot; property=&quot;content:encoded&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;Bien que le pain reste &lt;strong&gt;un aliment
        emblématique de la culture française&lt;/strong&gt;, il n’échappe pas aux évolutions des modes de vie. Selon une
        étude du Crédoc, publiée en 2017 par l’observatoire du pain, ce dernier subi un effet de génération négatif. Au
        même âge, les nouvelles générations consommeraient moins de pain que les anciennes. Cependant, en analysant d’un
        peu plus près leurs habitudes, il a été constaté qu’ils consommeraient plus de pain sous forme de sandwich ou
        hamburger que les générations précédentes.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;C’est donc pour répondre à une demande croissante de pain moelleux, type pain de mie, que nous avons
        imaginé « Le Moelleux Tradition ». &lt;strong&gt;Élaboré par le MOF, Jean-Yves Guinard&lt;/strong&gt;, sa
        recette, n’est réalisable que sur la base exclusive de farine de tradition Française « La Croquise ». Mis au
        point selon &lt;strong&gt;un procédé unique&lt;/strong&gt;, ce pain moelleux, à la recette innovante, se
        caractérise par &lt;strong&gt;une croûte très fine et une mie extrêmement moelleuse&lt;/strong&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Sans additif, sucre ni matière grasse&lt;/strong&gt;, sa composition des plus salutaire,
        saura séduire tous les clients en quêtes d’authenticité et de naturel. En effet, suite aux différentes crises
        sanitaires et médiatiques, les consommateurs se disent de plus en plus inquiets quant aux ingrédients qu’ils
        mangent. C’est pourquoi, ils sont plus impliqués et regardants quant aux composants de leurs aliments.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Dans une volonté constante d’accompagner au plus près nos artisans boulangers, nous avons conçu,
        spécialement pour l’occasion, une barquette des plus attrayantes. Inédite en boulangerie artisanale, cette
        barquette aux couleurs de la Croquise mettra en avant ce nouveau pain et lui apportera un maximum de visibilité.
        &lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Pour télécharger notre argumentaire de vente, cliquez sur le lien ci-dessous :&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.test.com/sites/all/themes/nexus/images/pdf-telecharger/pdf.pdf&quot;
        target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;u&gt;Télécharger l&#039;argumentaire&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;ul class=&quot;links inline&quot;&gt;&lt;li class=&quot;addtoany first
        last&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_target addtoany_list&quot; id=&quot;da2a_1&quot;&gt;
        &lt;a class=&quot;a2a_button_facebook&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;a class=&quot;a2a_button_twitter&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;a class=&quot;a2a_button_google_plus&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;a class=&quot;a2a_dd addtoany_share_save&quot; href=&quot;https://www.addtoany.com/share#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2Fcontent%2Ftest&amp;amp;title=La%20Croquise%20fait%20sa%20rentr%C3%A9e%20avec%20son%20Moelleux%20Tradition%20%21&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;

        &lt;/span&gt;
        &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
        &lt;!--//--&gt;&lt;![CDATA[//&gt;&lt;!--
        if(window.da2a)da2a.script_load();
        //--&gt;&lt;!]]&gt;
        &lt;/script&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
        &lt;/ul&gt;
    </description>
    <pubDate>Thu, 27 Sep 2018 13:08:31 +0000</pubDate>
</item>
```

I have this code for go through my RSS :

```
<?php
 $url = "myfile.xml";
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    // echo "<pre>".print_r(htmlspecialchars($item->description), true)."</pre>";
    var_dump($item->xpath('description/typeof="foaf:Image"'));
    // echo "<pre>".print_r($item->xpath("typeof=\"foaf:Image\""), true)."</pre>";
    $i++;
    if ($i < 4) {
        $itemsReturned[] = array(
            $item,
        );
    }
}
?>
```

And I (think I) need to use **typeof=\"foaf:Image** to get the image inside my description tag, but I have nothing in return, probably due to the format of data in this tag.

Comment: Your `description` element here contains _text_ only, so you can not go look for _elements_ inside it. You would need to decode this first using `html_entity_decode` or something like that.

Comment: I tried with htmlspecialchars, but this part wasn't detected as xml

Comment: You can’t do this in one go. You need to get the content of the description element first, decode _that_, and then proceed to go looking inside that for the element you are looking for.

Comment: Ok but how do I do that ?

Comment: Well you haven’t even told us how you parsed this to get the content into your `$rss` variable in the first place … (The content of that description might not necessarily be valid XML to begin with, so you might need to switch to an HTML parser for _this_ part.)

Comment: See update original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've ended up with, and it's working, if it could help...

```
preg_match('/img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $item->description, $image);
$image['src']
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've loaded $item from the sample data you've given, I hope this will work...

```
//$item = simplexml_load_string($data);
$content = "<content>".html_entity_decode($item->description)."</content>";
$content = str_replace("&title","title",$content);
$description = simplexml_load_string($content);
$img = $description->xpath('//img[@typeof="foaf:Image"]');
echo (string)$img[0]["src"];
```

This takes the `<item>` element and extracts the `<description>` element and then decodes it.  This is then loaded into another SimpleXML element (as it's a HTML fragment, I enclose it in a root tag) and uses XPath to find the right `<img>` tag with the corresponding typeof value.

The last line just uses the first match from the XPath expression and outputs the src attribute.

There are some rogue attributes in there which is what the replace of `&title` does is remove them to enable the load to work.